# Load a category collection with store-specific data

Tags: category, collection-filtering, scope

I have found plenty of questions and answers regarding how to load categories from a particular store, but this is a different issue.

My problem is, having loaded the categories that I want, their attribute data is always the default / global value.

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'description')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
    ->addIdFilter('31,32,33,34') // has to be a string, array doesn't work!
    ->setStoreId(2);
```

In the above example, the names and descriptions that I get back are the default values, not the ones set for store ID 2. It looks like `setStoreId` does nothing.

I know that the categories themselves are not connected with a particular store view, but the attributes are: in the admin panel, you can set values per store view, per website and globally. I've set them per store view.

I've tried `->addStoreFilter(2)` but Mage_Catalog_Model_Category_Collection doesn't support that, I get a PHP fatal error. Looks like it's a product-specific filter.

Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Comment: Looking at the models, I'm not convinced you actually can :S. The collection has `setProductStoreId` which allows you to set where the products will come from but `joinUrlRewrite` for example uses `Mage::app()->getStore()` which implies you can't easily join the URLs for a different store. You could try `setStoreId` on the model before `getCollection` but I'm not sure it'll have the desired effect.

Comment: Seems it does work, I was just suffering from the side-effects of another issue (see answer below). In my case I'm loading the collection in a front-end block so I imagine store id is set implicitly. Not sure if it still works when using code outside of the store environment (e.g. in a cron job).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I've found the answer.

In fact the collection, under normal circumstances, works fine. It turned out that in my case, some required attributes weren't set, which was causing this side-effect.

Fun fact: required attributes are not enforced when adding categories via the API.

Somehow, if the "Available Product Listing Sort By" is undefined at "Default" level (and I suspect any required attribute would be the same), then store-specific values are not loaded.

Funny how store-specific data is affected by omissions in default-level data. I did try setting this attribute at the store level, so that at store level the category data was complete, but it still didn't help. Only fixing it at default level solved my problem.

Comment: Aha, funny you fell afoul of that particular issue. We ran across something similar with products a couple of weeks ago. I believe it affects all EAV models.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I didn't think to check my products... better go do that now :|

Answer (score 0):

I got the correct storeview values by emulating the specific storeview by hand using the class `Mage_Core_Model_App_Emulation`

```
/** @var \Mage_Core_Model_App_Emulation $appEmulation */
                                $appEmulation = \Mage::getSingleton('core/app_emulation');

                                //Start environment emulation of the specified store
                                $initialEnvironmentInfo = $appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId);

                                /** @var \Mage_Catalog_Model_Category $_category */
                                $_category = \Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load($catId);
                                $_category->load($catId); //Load again because some attributes wont be visible/available
                                $categoryName               = $_category->getName(); //Get the storeview specific categoryname


// ....

                                //Stop environment emulation and restore original store
                                $appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo);
```